# $_SESSION not updated until a couple of refreshes or waiting

Tags: php, ajax, session

So what's happening is when I login and do a location.reload() the $_SESSION doesn't update until I have refreshed a couple of times or wait for like 30-60 seconds.
It seems more like it's timebased but can't tell for sure.

So I've been checking stackoverflow but many of the questions are solved with doing 301 to from non-www. to www. (which I have done in .htaccess).
I have also put my session_start(); at the top of the body.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
        <div class="right"><span class="button menuButton dropdownTrigger" data-dropdown-id="1"><a>Logga In</a></div>
<?php else: ?>
        <div class="right"><span class="button menuButton"><a>Profil</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So that's how the code that should be changed when I refresh.
It works it's just that it takes way to long/to many refreshes until it does.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "login/checklogin.php",
data: "myusername=" + username + "&mypassword=" + password,
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function (html) {
//console.log(html.response + ' ' + html.username);
if (html.response === 'true') {
//location.assign("../index.php");
      location.reload();
      return html.username;
 } else {
      $("#message").html(html.response);
      }
 },
 error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus);
       console.log(errorThrown);
 },
 beforeSend: function () {
       $("#message").html("<p class='text-center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'></p>");
 }
});
```

This is the php code that I access which reload website and return value.

If you need anymore information don't hesitate to tell me!
Thanks in advance!

*Update on the duplicate questions*
It's not the same since it doesn't help to change page.

*Update to check with Ed*

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
```

Have also tested this and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

*Update to show where $_SESSION is used*

```
//If max attempts not exceeded, continue
// Checks password entered against db password hash
if (password_verify($mypassword, $result['password']) && $result['verified'] == '1') {

//Success! Register $myusername, $mypassword and return "true"
$success = 'true';
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php session variables not updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388126/php-session-variables-not-updating)

Comment: You wrote, "I have also put my session_start(); at the top of the body." Don't put it at the top of the `<BODY>` tag. Put it at the top of *every single **script***, before any output of any kind, including the `<HTML>` opening tag. You want to run it once and only once per request, before any output.

Comment: @EdCottrell Do you mean like this? Check my update

Comment: @MrNaitX Yes. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php.

Comment: @EdCottrell Please check my update in the text! :)

Comment: @MrNaitX It sounds like you're adding `session_start()` multiple times in the same script. That's not correct; see what I said above: "You want to run it **once and only once per request**, before any output."

Comment: @EdCottrell Okey! Then I didn't understand you correctly, I had 1 before and added 2 cause I thought that was what you meant. But now I only have 1 above <!doctype> but it's still the same!

Comment: @MrNaitX It's hard to give you any further help because you haven't posted whatever code you use to set any session variables. Your question currently lacks a [mcve] and is subject to closure.

Comment: @EdCottrell Now I have added where the $_SESSION is used.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `session_start()` inside an `if` block. As I have said several times in the comments on your post, you need to run `session_start()` once and only once on ***every request***. If you only run it when `password_verify()` is successful, you won't be using your session on any other requests. That's your problem.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session ***or resumes the current one*** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

To be safe, make it the first line of code executed every time the page loads, unless you are doing some very fancy stuff (which you are not) and know exactly what you are doing.

To be extra clear, your code should look something like this:

```
<?php

session_start(); // PUT THIS HERE

//If max attempts not exceeded, continue
// Checks password entered against db password hash
if (password_verify($mypassword, $result['password']) && $result['verified'] == '1') {

    //Success! Register $myusername, $mypassword and return "true"
    $success = 'true';

    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
```

Again, you need to make sure to run `session_start()` on all other requests, too, not just the login-handler.

Also, you have a number of "code smells," such as (1) comparison using `==`, (2) comparing to the string `'1'` instead of the integer `1`, and (3) setting a variable to the string `'true'`. I'd strongly recommend reading everything on [phptherightway.com](http://www.phptherightway.com) before writing any more code.

Answer (score 0):

So I tested turning off caching and then it worked. Have talked to my hosting and they think it's in their end and not mine.